# How much is too much (processes, threads)

Tags: linux, threads, limits

I wonder if I have too much processes and if systemd is getting overloaded. When I run `ps aux | wc -l` O get "840" If I run `ps -e H | wc -l` I have around 5k (5128 to be exact), substracting the process count, this makes around 4288 threads. Is this too much for ubuntu and how can I know if systemd is overloaded for example?
On this server environment I have 48 cores and 128gb RAM.

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted as it seems like a legitimate question? However, perhaps you could re-phrase the title?

Comment: This question is effectively 'How long is a piece of string?'

Comment: @lain couldn't have said it better

Answer (score 2):

"How many pieces I can fit to trunk of my car?" -- pieces of what? 5k Lego pieces would probably fit, 5k cans of beverages probably not.

It's not so much about the process/thread count, it's more about how CPU/memory/disk/network intensive those are. Please be more detailed. :) But for a relatively powerful server which you have that amount of mostly idle processes/threads is not a big deal. It's a different story if they all actually attempt to do something.